# meteor-testing tutorial fails

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I started the [meteor-testing tutorial](http://www.meteortesting.com/chapter/velocity), but the 2nd automatic generated test fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'url' of undefined
```

So it seems that the client variable is not defined. Did anybody experience similar issues? (btw is there a way to debug this)

i'm using ubuntu 14.04 with

```
Meteor 1.2.0.2
node v4.0.0
xolvio:cucumber       0.19.4_1  CucumberJS for Velocity
```

---

**Update:**

Generated test code intests/cucumber/features/step_definitions/sample_steps.js:

```
// You can include npm dependencies for support files in  tests/cucumber/package.json
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = function () {
  // You can use normal require here, cucumber is NOT run in a Meteor context (by design)
  var url = require('url');
  // 1st TEST OK
  this.Given(/^I am a new user$/, function () {
    server.call('reset'); // server is a connection to the mirror
  });
  // 2nd TEST FAIL
  this.When(/^I navigate to "([^"]*)"$/, function (relativePath) {
    // process.env.ROOT_URL always points to the mirror
    client.url(url.resolve(process.env.ROOT_URL, relativePath));
  });
...
};
```

Comment: did you put the automation code under /tests/cucumber/features?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Can you please also run this with `VELOCITY_DEBUG=1` and post the problem on the chimp repo (https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/issues), then we can come back here after we have the answer

Comment: [at] Kyll: those tests are autogenerated, nevertheless I updated my question.
@TheMeteorTestManual thx, I'll do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was said to file an [issue in the chimp repository](https://github.com/xolvio/chimp/issues/142), where I was pointed to the solution:

```
// 2nd TEST FAIL
this.When(/^I navigate to "([^"]*)"$/, function (relativePath) {
  // REPLACE client with browser
  browser.url(url.resolve(process.env.ROOT_URL, relativePath));
});
```

This is a short fix, but I'm not sure whether you should later rather use client (seems to be wrapper for different environments).

---

**Update: ** meanwhile this was fixed, no adaption necessary anymore

Comment: Yes, sorry about that! client/browser/driver are all the same alias to the webdriver instance